# Duplicate items are not added to the list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying below java code and would want to add all the matching items to a list based on the input list. Below I've the input list, look up list and the return matching list. Currenlty, the below code fails when we have duplicate values in the input list. Can someone advice how I can resolve this ? Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.time.YearMonth;
 import java.util.*;
 import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;


public class PeriodTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Input
    List<YearMonth> yearMonths = Arrays.asList(YearMonth.of(2016, 9), YearMonth.of(2016, 9));

    //Look up
    List<PeriodCode> periodCodes = Arrays.asList(new PeriodCode(2016, 9), new PeriodCode(2017, 9));

    //Code
    List<PeriodCode> actualOutput = periodCodes.stream().filter(item -> yearMonths.contains(YearMonth.of(item.getYear(), item.getMonth()))).collect(toList());
    List<PeriodCode> expectedOutput = Arrays.asList
            (
                    new PeriodCode(2016, 9),
                    new PeriodCode(2016, 9)
            );

    System.out.print(actualOutput.size() == expectedOutput.size());//false 1 vs 2

}

private static class PeriodCode {

    private int year;
    private int month;

    PeriodCode(int year, int month) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PeriodCode)) return false;

        PeriodCode that = (PeriodCode) o;

        if (year != that.year) return false;
        return month == that.month;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = year;
        result = 31 * result + month;
        return result;
    }

    int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `yearMonths` doesn't contain a value for 2017, so the filter will not keep the PeriodCode for 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you expect duplicates to be gone, since you haven't actually done anything to remove them.

Adding `.distinct()` to the stream chain might help, though.

UPDATE: write

```
periodCodes.stream()
    .flatMap(periodCode -> 
        yearMonths.stream()
            .filter(YearMonth.of(periodCode.getYear(), periodCode.getMonth())::equals)
            .map(ym -> periodCode))
    .collect(toList())
```

Comment: no, I want the duplicates to show up in the returned list.

Comment: @Reddy, then why are you filtering an input stream that doesn't have duplicates?  You're starting with `periodCodes.stream()`, which doesn't have duplicates, not `yearMonths.stream()` which does.  Did you switch them around?

Comment: I think the problem the OP is stating isn't that duplicates should be removed, but that they aren't getting two values out when the `yearMonths` list has duplicates. The OP doesn't realize that the `yearMonths` can contain duplicates, but it is the fact that `yearMonths` doesn't have a value for 2017 that is causing one of the periods to be filtered out.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman yes, I agree. But I want the transformed list to be of type PeriodCode. So I started with periodCodes.stream() so I can get the match based on yearMonths stream and collect to new periodCodes list.

Comment: @Hank D its the other way around. I want the duplicates from yearMonths to show up in the new period codes list.

Comment: You need to convert yearMonths to PeriodCodes then.  What you're asking for makes no real sense.  It may be worth trying to write this code without streams first.

Comment: I agree.  stream/iterate over yearMonths if you want one output for every yearMonth. Then in your filter, convert item to a PeriodCode and look it up in your period codes list

Comment: okay some more context. I don't need one output for every yearMonth. If its not there in the period code list, it can be discarded, but if its there(can be dups too) I need the matching periodcode one for each matching entry. I just wanted to try and see if this is possible. I was thinking may be there is a way to still iterate over period codes and filter the year month. The above code works fine when there are no dups no matter what the input stream is.

Comment: So you want to *repeat* the period code as many times as there are yearMonth matches?

Comment: Then you need `periodCodes.stream().flatMap(periodCode -> yearMonths.stream().filter(YearMonth.of(item.getYear(), item.getMonth())::equals).map(ym -> periodCode)).collect(toList())`.

Comment: compile error while trying to use the above -- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to <unknown>
code

Comment: Oh, oops, item should be periodCode.  Does that help?

Comment: Works.Please go ahead and update the answer. Thank you sir for being prompt.